# Trouble installing Spock plugin into Eclipse 2019

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, spock, jspresso

I'm using Eclipse 2019-03
I'm trying to install Spock Eclipse plugin. I have Groovy tools installed. When I move the install button from the browser Eclipse marketplace over into eclipse, nothing appears to happen except for the marketplace window pops open.
 When I search for Spock in Eclipse > install new plugins > Eclipse marketplace I can't find it.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Spock Eclipse plugin is no more maintain.
You should consider using IntelliJ IDEA which has a much better support of Groovy and Spock also.
Kind regards
Maxime

Comment: my problem with Intellj IDEA is that to get what I want like spring I need to spend $300-$400 for a licensed version. Eclipse is free.

Comment: Only if your company pays for you. If you pay yourself it is about $120 per year if you want to update continuously and thus have a subscription.